# How do I code a recursive a recursive method that forms the integer sum of all valid numerics substrings in a string?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, numbers

For example, the result of `toNumber("3.2ac4.8rw2")` would be 10 (=3.2+4.8+2).

My Code that I created is below. However it is failing at what I tend to do and I cannot come up with a solution.

```
public class toNumber {
public static int toNumber(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    char next = s.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isDigit(next)) {
        return Character.digit(next, 10) + toNumber(s.substring(1));
    } 
    else 
    {
        return toNumber(s.substring(1));
    }
}
public static int to1Number(String input)
{
    if(input ==null || input.length()==0)
    return 0;

    if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(input.length()-1)))
        return input.charAt(input.length()-1) + 
                toNumber(input.substring(0, input.length()-1));
    else
        return toNumber(input.substring(0, input.length()-1));

}

public static void main(String []args)
{
    String input;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("please enter some input");
    input = kb.nextLine();


    System.out.println(to1Number(input));

}
}
```

**I Tested it like this **

> please enter some input
>
> my input: t4343
>
> result returned: 62

Comment: Aside from the fact you're not handling floating point numbers as in your first example, I'm pretty sure you don't mean `input.charAt(input.length()-1) + ...`, but rather `Character.getNumericValue(that expression) + ...`.

Comment: This isn't a good fit for a recursive solution. Why do you want to recurse?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it recursive:

```
public int toNumber(String str) {
    char ch = str.charAt(0);
    int count = Character.isDigit(ch) ? Character.getNumericValue(ch) : 0;
    return str.length() > 1 ? count + toNumber(str.substring(1)) : count;
}
```

Or java 8 using streams without recursion:

```
public int toNumber(String str) {
    return str.chars()
            .mapToObj(i->(char)i)
            .filter(Character::isDigit)
            .mapToInt(Character::getNumericValue)
            .sum();
}
```

Or with a standard loop without recursion:

```
public int toNumber(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            count += Character.getNumericValue(ch);
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

---

If you also want to count floating numbers, a solution using regular expressions would be the simpler one:

```
private double toNumber(String str) {
    ArrayList<String> nums = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d*)?"); // If you want to limit the decimal count to 1: "\\d{1}(\\.\\d{1})?"
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        nums.add(matcher.group());
    }

    return nums.stream().mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).sum();
}
```

Comment: wow, simpler then I thought Thank you. What do the Questions marks do?

Comment: thats a so called ternary operator. It will check the condition before the questionmark, if its true it will return the value before the colon, if its false the value after the colon.

Comment: ok, I haven't learned about ternary operators yet.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              How would you edit the code to get it to add these numbers to a sum of 10?      "3.2ac4.8rw2"

Comment: well that depends: imagine you have "t4343a4.3", do you want 4343 to be the number 4343 or are you setting a limit to numbers from 1-10 resulting in 4343 being 4,3,4,3? Also how much numbers do you want to count after the decimal point?